# NordVPN gets stuck in reconnecting state leaving no access to internet

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Usually this happens when resuming laptop from sleep having previously been connected. When the client tries to reconnect is just hangs indefinitely and shows **reconnecting** in the status.

The annoying this is I cannot cancel this, or kill the nord vpn process, leaving with no open other than to reboot.

I'm using the latest version on NordVPN linux client `NordVPN Version 3.10.0`.

I've tried various settings changes, kill switch on/off etc. I'm currently on the following settings.

```
Technology: OpenVPN
Protocol: UDP
Firewall: enabled
Kill Switch: disabled
CyberSec: disabled
Obfuscate: disabled
Notify: enabled
Auto-connect: disabled
IPv6: disabled
DNS: x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x
```

Is there a way to kill nord VPN using the usual method of searching in system monitor, doesn't seem to work as the process pops straight back up again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue and use this little script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sudo pkill -9 -f nordvpn
sudo iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat --flush
sudo iptables -t mangle --flush
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables -X
```

It kills the nordvpn process and resets the iptables.
After that, you can connect again.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to update this for anyone else that has problems and the previous suggest solution does not work for them, just as it didn't for me.

I contacted nordvpn online help, and after faffing about for a while, the thing that did work was the following.

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -F INPUT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -F OUTPUT
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Even though that immediately got me connected, I actually use openvpn so had to issue the following command after

```
nordvpn set technology openvpn
```

to get back to using openvpn.

Hope this helps if the other solution doesn't work for whomever.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me finally